# Apply a property for a part of text of textblock in WPF

Tags: wpf, textblock

i want , when a part of text of textblock is 'Thomas' , around the text be blue.

How do i do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a converter:

```
public class StringPropertyContainsThomasConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if(value != null) {
            if(value.ToString().Contains("Thomas")) return Brushes.Blue; //replace with whatever color you want
        }
        return Brushes.White;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Usage in XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StringPropertyContainsThomasConverter x:Key="StringPropertyContainsThomasConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<TextBlock Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self},
                                Path=Text,
                                Converter={StaticResources StringPropertyContainsThomasConverter}}"/>
```